# directshow H.264 encoder which never cause memory leak

Tags: directshow, h.264

I'm developping H.264 capture application executed on Windows XP SP3(32bit).

The application cause memory leak when I implement Capture Test
(I'm checking Virtual Size colum of "Process Explorer").

When I change directshow encoder filter, amount of leak is changed.
So I'm suspecting directshow H.264 filter(encoder or multiplexor or both) as the cause of the memory leak.

Would you please tell me if you have heard "Free" directshow H.264 filter which never cause memory leak?

---- Follow up 2015-07-09 ----
I execute the application on WindowsXP: leaked
I execute the application on Windows 7 : not leaked

Are there any difference related to memory allocation/free between XP and 7...?

---- Follow up 2015-07-10 ----
I checked constructed graph on WindowsXP and Windows7 using GraphStudioNext.
H.264 Encoder : the same CLSID between WindowsXP and Windows7
H.264 Multiplexor : the same CLSID between WindowsXP and Windows7

Now I have attempted the H.264 filters below.

  H.264 encoder: ffdshow_rev3572_20100913_clsid, AX_components H264 encoder, x264vfw
  H.264 multiplexor: GDCL-H.264Multiplexor(updated 05 Jun 2015)

On both platforms, graph is below.
[USB Camera]---->[Smart Tee]---->[H.264 Encoder]---->[H.264 Mux]--->[File Writer]

matter of concern:

- In GraphStudioNext's Filter Propaties, WindowsXP using quartz.dll,
  but Windows7 using proppage.dll. Is this difference important..?
- On Windows XP, ALLOCATOR PROPATIES are exists, but 7 are not exists.

Comment: The filters available on different versions of Windows differ, also each system might have different 3rd party filters that are inserted into the graph. You can enable the graphs to be output to the Running Object Table (ROT)and then use GraphStudio to connect to the remote graph to see what has actually been constructed.

Comment: thanks. I'm checking it.

Comment: On Win7(32bit), GraphStudioNext(0.7.0.430)  returns E_NOINTERFACE(0x80004002) when I connect to the ROT. I already register v6.0's proppage.dll and quartz.dll. Would you know anything about it?

Comment: ↑sorry, GraphEditNext worked. I have to copy the proppage.dll to C:\WIndows\System32 and then "regsvr32 proppage.dll"

Comment: So the entire graph is the same on both platforms?

Comment: I think it may help to determine which filter is leaking memory e.g. codec or mux. Also, which codec and mux are you using?

Comment: Yes. Both platforms are the same graph.

Comment: I was pointed out to increase more comments, so I write additional information on my question.

Comment: >I think it may help to determine which filter is leaking memory e.g. codec or mux. 
I'm sorry, would you please teach me how to isolate codec and mux?

Comment: So is your issue solved by using the ffdshow/GDCL mux combination? (AFAIK ffdshow uses x264 under the hood).

Comment: You can isolate the encoder filter by constructing a minimal graph in GraphStudio/GraphStudioNext manually and e.g. insert a decoder/null renderer after the encoder and monitor memory usage/behaviour. Then repeat with mux after the encoder.

Comment: > So is your issue solved by using the ffdshow/GDCL mux combination?
No.

Comment: decoder/null renderer after the encoder and monitor memory usage/behaviour. 　... I'm sorry, please tell me concrete example.

Comment: Construct [USB Camera]---->[Smart Tee]---->[H.264 Encoder]---->[Null renderer] This may confirm that the problem is not in the encoder.

Comment: The first question here how do you tell the leak. Task Manager? Not serious. If it is leaking, then having it running long enough you hit "out of memory" condition, do you have it?

Comment: Agree with @RomanR. Only if the leak is serious, would I go through effort of trying to track it down. I had assumed that you're running some long running application...

Comment: @RomanR.  I checked "virtual size" on process explorer. I've been running my application for about 13hours. I compared virtual size between the time just starting capture test and the time about 13hours passed. Therefore, virtual size increased about 40,000KB. "out of memory" condition is not occured, but I think the condition will possibly occur after long time.

Comment: > Construct [USB Camera]---->[Smart Tee]---->[H.264 Encoder]---->[Null renderer]   thanks, I'm  trying it.

Comment: I would not qualify this as memory leak (even though it is still possibly a leak). Too many things involved, it could simply be heap manager consuming address space more aggressively and not releasing it just because there is no need and memory pressure. Steady and well-measured increase in Private Bytes would be perhaps the metric I would take as a warning.

Comment: @RomanR. "Peak Private Bytes" increased about 7,000KB for 13hours.

Comment: You are interested in checking whether it is a continuous increase, also whether it leaks away with restarting with restarted graph.